# Finding all complex solutions $z$ of an equation involving $z$ and its conjugate $\bar z$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find all complex solutions of the equation: $2z + 2i\bar z = 0.$

This is what I have done so far:

Let $z = x + yi$ and $\bar z = x - yi$ and then substitute into the equation.

$2(x + yi) + 2i(x - yi) = 0$

$2x + 2yi + 2xi - 2yi^2 = 0$

$2x + 2yi + 2xi - 2y(-1) = 0$

$2x + 2yi + 2xi + 2y = 0$

$2x + 2y + 2yi + 2xi = 0$

$2(x + y) + 2(x + y)i = 0$

So now we setup the two equations which would be the same

$2(x + y) = 0$

$2(x + y) = 0$

When I checked the solutions to this on Wolfram Alpha it simply said $y = -x. $
Have I gone about this question the wrong way? What is the best way to approach this question and what are the correct solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Did you realize that $2(x+y)=0\iff y=-x$?  You could also say $2(x+y)(1+i)=0\iff x+y=0$

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric interpretation:

$$z+i \overline{z}=0.$$

The complex conjugate of $z$, $\overline{z}$, is found by reflecting $z$ by the real axis.  Multiplying by $i$ is rotating by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise ($90^\circ$).

Take any point $z=(\alpha,-\alpha)$ on the line $y=-x$.  Reflect it by the real axis and rotate by $90^\circ$ counterclockwise. You will get $-z=(-\alpha,\alpha)$ and when you add this to $z$, the result is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help as well!

Comment: Sure.  You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer $2(x+y)=0\iff x+y=0$ is the same as Wolfram Alpha's $y=-x$.

You could have said $2(x+y)+2(x+y)i=0\iff 2(x+y)(1+i)=0\iff x+y=0$.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. So this would mean that the solutions would be x = 0 and y = 0?

Comment: $x$ could be any real number, as long as $y=-x$; for example, $z$ could be $7-7i$

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the "acceptance."  $z$ has to be a real multiple of $1-i$